# How can I know which button clicked on it inside notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have three buttons in each notification (the main notification button, the timer button, and the disable button).

- The **main notification button** runs the foreground service
- The **timer button** runs the foreground service, but shows the toast message
- The **disable button** removes notification from status bar

Is there a way to use one foreground service for all three buttons? If so, how do I determine which button was clicked within the service? Or must I create three foreground services for each button?

**My Code**

```
PendingIntent pendingIntentMain = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class).putExtra("main", "a"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentTimer = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class).putExtra("timer", "b"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pendingIntentDisable = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, ForegroundService.class).putExtra("disable", "c"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, String.valueOf(NOTIFICATION_ID))
    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, context.getString(R.string.timer), pendingIntentTimer)
    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, context.getString(R.string.disable), pendingIntentDisable)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntentMain)
    .setOngoing(true)
    .setAutoCancel(false)
    .setShowWhen(false)
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.tap_to_enable_service))
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

**Foreground Service**

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.w("ABC", "" + intent.getStringExtra("main"));
        Log.w("ABC", "" + intent.getStringExtra("timer"));
        Log.w("ABC", "" + intent.getStringExtra("disable"));
        Log.w("ABC", "" + intent.getExtras());
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

The `Log.w` inside `onStartCommand` shows nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to create different Foreground Services, You can use Intent Action instead of passing intent with data. Like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this , ClipTextObserverService.class);
intent.setAction("specify_name_of_the_action")

PendingIntent.getService(
            this,
            1464,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
```

Change the Flag accordingly. Pass this pendingIntent in addAction() method.
Then Check for the action in onStartCommand() method of Service.Like,

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent Intent , Int flags , Int startId) {

switch (intent.getAction()) {
 case "your_action_name":
    // TODO == Perform your action here.
    break;
}

return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags , startId);
}
```

Comment: That is working thank you, But is there any different between putExtra and setAction?

Comment: Yes, putExtra() is used when we want to pass some value with the intent whereas setAction() just passes the name of the action. It's specifically designed for this kind of tasks where we just want to do something on intent received.

Comment: I got it. Thanks